# Why django displays unreadable characters in IE?

Tags: django, internet-explorer

My django code works in chrome and firefox but in IE the webpage displays unreadable charactars. The following is my code setting:

```
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf8'
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf8'
```

and the template files are saved as utf8 format, but my template file has some other language besides english. That non-english part is not readable.

Should I change some setting of django ? Most of the visitors of my website may use IE, so this is a big problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have charset explicitly provided in template? Does the font from CSS (if any) support necessary characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you add this meta to your base html?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```